# Access violation writing location 0x00000000. memset function issues

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void newBuffer(char* outBuffer, size_t sz) {
    outBuffer = new char[sz];
}

int main(void) {

    const char* abcd = "ABCD";
    char* foo;
    foo = NULL;
    size_t len = strlen(abcd);
    cout<<"Checkpoint 1"<<endl;
    newBuffer(foo, len);
    cout<<"Checkpoint 2"<<endl;

    cout<<"Checkpoint 2-A"<<endl;
    memset(foo, '-', len);
    cout<<"Checkpoint 3"<<endl;
    strncpy(foo, abcd, len);
    cout<<"Checkpoint 4"<<endl;
    cout << foo << endl;

    int hold;
    cin>>hold;
    return 0;
```

}

This program crashes between checkpoint 2-1 and 3. What it tries to do is to set the char array foo to the char '-', but it fails because of some access issues. I do not understand why this happens. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Unless this is a toy/educational question: Another prime example why you should use `std::string` or `std::vector` for things like this in C++!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `newBuffer` function should accept the first parameter by reference so that changes made to it inside the function are visible to the caller:

```
void newBuffer(char*& outBuffer, size_t sz) {
    outBuffer = new char[sz];
}
```

As it is now, you assign the result of `new char[sz]` to the local variable `outBuffer` which is only a *copy* of the caller's `foo` variable, so when the function returns it's as if nothing ever happened (except you leaked memory).

Also you have a problem in that you are allocating the buffer to the size of the length of `ABCD` which is 4. That means you can hold up to 3 characters in that buffer because one is reserved for the NUL-terminator at the end. You need to add `+ 1` to the length somewhere (I would do it in the call to the function, not inside it, because `newBuffer` shouldn't be specialised for C-strings). `strncpy` only NUL-terminates the buffer if the source string is short enough, so in this case you are only lucky that there happens to be a `0` in memory after your buffer you allocated.

Also don't forget to `delete[] foo` in `main` after you're done with it (although it doesn't really matter for a program this size).

Comment: Dang! It was this trivial. I did not notice that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because your `newBuffer` function doesn't actually work. The easiest way to fix it would be to change the declaration to `void newBuffer (char *&outBuffer, size_t sz)`. As it's written, the address of the newly allocated memory doesn't actually get stored into main's `foo` because the pointer is passed by value.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer by value. You would need to pass either a reference to the pointer, or the address of the pointer.

That said, using the return value would be better in my view:

```
char* newBuffer(size_t sz) {
    return new char[sz];
}
```

When written this way, the `newBuffer` function doesn't really seem worthwhile. You don't need it. You can use `new` directly and that would be clearer.

Of course, if you are using C++ then this is all rather pointless. You should be using `string`, smart pointers etc. You should not have any need to call `new` directly. Once you fix the bug you are talking about in this question you will come across the problem that your string is not null-terminated and that the buffer is too short to hold the string since you forgot to allocate space for the null-terminator. One of the nice things about C++ is that you can escape the horrors of string handling in C.